# Paginate on grouped queries

Tags: laravel, date, group-by, pagination

I'm writing a system to follow cash flow. The users register transactions they made:
([transactions index screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/buZKV.png))
but I need to get these transactions separated by date. I tried using an Request to index, but it doesn't looked the best pratice (it worked, however). Now I'm trying to do another aproach: retrieve all transactions and paginate them by date. Is it possible?

ps: maybe grouping by months helps? like:

```
$transactions = Transaction::all()->groupBy(function($transaction) {
    return Carbon::parse($transaction->date)->format('m-Y');
});
```

this returns:

```
{
    "03-2019": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "Teste 1",
            "date": "2019-03",
            "user_id": 1,
            "description": "Primeiro teste, com entrada de 1500 reais.",
            "value": "1500.00",
            "flow": 1,
            "created_at": "2019-03-24 05:39:45",
            "updated_at": "2019-03-24 05:39:45"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "title": "Teste 2",
            "date": "2019-03",
            "user_id": 1,
            "description": "Segundo teste, com saída de 500 reais.",
            "value": "500.00",
            "flow": 0,
            "created_at": "2019-03-24 05:39:45",
            "updated_at": "2019-03-24 05:39:45"
        }
    ]
}
```

ps²: yeah, front-end is in brazilian portuguese and english isn't my native language.. :)

Comment: You may need to use a library for it as you want to 'paginate collections' however Laravel's `paginate()` is for Eloquent ORM

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
<?php 

use Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator;

$transactions = Transaction::all()->groupBy(function($transaction) {
  return Carbon::parse($transaction->date)->format('m-Y'); 
});

//new LengthAwarePaginator($data,$countOfData,$perPage,$currentPage);
$transactions=new LengthAwarePaginator($transactions->forPage($currentPage,$perPage),$transactions->count(),$currentPage);
```

Hope it helps...